# How can I see the date multiple files were created on git?

Tags: git, github

I want to see the date of git creation (date of first commit where they were added) of all the files on a specified directory.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @David: I don't think there is anything to try except clicking buttons on GitHub's web UI. I can't see any buttons for this either.

Comment: The date of a commit is within the Git tree itself. If you try `git log` you can see the date of all past commits. That alone is a decent starting point, there's plenty to try.

Comment: Also, my previous comment no longer applies. Clearly, polvoazul [had tried something](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10975655/815632).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'll break my solution into steps.

#### Get a list of all files in the repository

```
$ git ls-files
```

This returns a list of relative paths of all files in the repository.

#### Get the SHA-1 of the first commit of a given file:

```
$ git rev-list HEAD <file> | tail -n 1
```

This will return a list of all parentless commits for a given file, in reverse chronological order. The last one is the SHA-1 hash of the first commit for the given file.

You can verify this by running `git log --raw <hash>`. You should see something like:

```
commit <commit_hash>
Author: Susy Q <suzy@example.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 24 12:36:34 2011 -0400

    Add new module 'example.py'

:000000 100644 0000000... <hash>... A  example.py
```

#### Show the date of a given commit

```bash
$ git show -s --format="%ci" <hash>
```

#### Bringing it all together in a bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(git ls-files)
do
    HASH=$(git rev-list HEAD "$file" | tail -n 1)
    DATE=$(git show -s --format="%ci" $HASH --)
    printf "%-35s %s\n  %s\n" "$file" $HASH: "$DATE"
done
```

Comment: Nice git commands there which i have not heard before! Thanks!

Comment: Really cool!  NB: If you have spaces in your file names or paths, then add the following to the beginning of the script, before the `for` statement: `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")` (from http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html)

Comment: Should it be possible to sort by date?

Answer (score 3):

Well, i devised a solution which is not elegant but sort of works:

```
for file in dir/*; do echo -e "$file: \t\t `git log $file|grep Date|tail -1`"; done
```

it works by running `git log` on each file and then `grep`ing it to get only the dates of each commit regarding that file. Then `tail -1` ensures that i will only get the date of the first commit. The `echo -e "..."` is there just so that it prints the info in a (not-so)friendly way!

Comment: Even better formating using printf:

`for i in *; do printf "%-35s  \`git log $i|grep Date|tail -1\`\n" $i:; done`

Comment: As brilliantly hackish as your solution is, one really shouldn't be using `git log` for scripting purposes. =)

Comment: @David Can you tell me why? *not intended to sound arrogant :)*

Comment: Por supuesto (y no te preocupes!). `git log` produces a lot of extraneous text that you don't need, and may cause trouble for a regex. For example, what happens if "Date" is in your last commit message? Git has a whole host of tools meant to interact with the revision tree. You should use those tools instead.

Comment: For reference, if you had prepended the BOL character (`^`) to your regex, as Johnsyweb had, your regular expression would only catch lines with the true Date on them (commit messages are indented).

Comment: Just passing on change to ``for file in dir/*; do echo -e "`git log --pretty=Date:%ci $file|grep Date|tail -1` $file"; done`` to get the dates in front in a sortable format